# The simple one to make callback in android - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, callback, listener

I am trying to figure out how callback work and the simplest way to do it, but I can't manage to solve it

This is my Listener Interface

```
public interface OnTestingCBListener {
     void onSuccessCB(String SomeValue);}
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
OnCreate(){
    //FIRST
    deviceSetup();
}

public void deviceSetup() {
    String DeviceID = "asdfg";
    final String[] FirebaseID = {""};

    //SECOND
    GetFireBaseIDCall(new OnTestingCBListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccessCB(String ResultValue) {
            //FOURTH
            FirebaseID[0] = ResultValue;
        }
    }, "Value1", "Value2");

    //FIFTH
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Result: "+DeviceID+"#"+FirebaseID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

OnTestingCBListener onTestingCBListener;
public void GetFireBaseIDCall(OnTestingCBListener onTestingCBListener, String x, String y){
    if(x.equals("Value1") && y.equals("Value2")) {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                final String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                Log.d("newToken", "Success :)");

                //THIRD
                onTestingCBListener.onSuccessCB(newToken);
            }
        });

        Log.d("newToken", "Failed :(");
    }
}
```

It's doesn't work, any solution?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android) will be of use to you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow these steps:**

1. First you have to make your activity extend the callback interface like:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity(), OnTestingCBListener {
   ```
2. Then implement all non implemented functions of that interface in your activity.
3. Then create an object of that interface and initialize it in onCreate() of your Activity like:

   ```
   OnTestingCBListener onTestingCBListener;
   ```

   in onCreate() initialize it like:

   ```
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           onTestingCBListener = this
       }
   ```
4. Then call it's functions whenever you want like:

   ```
   onTestingCBListener.onSuccessCB(newToken);
   ```

Comment: Thanks!!, the problem was solved when I Initialized it

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the log `Log.d("newToken", "Success :)");` is logged in logcat hence we are certain that `onSuccessCB()` of the local `onTestingCBListener` listener is triggered.

The only issue with your code is that you are showing the `Toast` too early, and before the `Firebase` callback gets called, so the `onTestingCBListener`'s onSucess() gets called after your Toast is shown, so transfer the `Toast` message within the listener `onSucess()`; so change below part of your code to be

```
...
//SECOND
GetFireBaseIDCall(new OnTestingCBListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccessCB(String ResultValue) {
        //FOURTH
        FirebaseID[0] = ResultValue;
        //FIFTH
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Result: "+DeviceID+"#"+FirebaseID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}, "Value1", "Value2");
...
```

Also please notice that `Firebase` is working in background thread so it takes a while to get your data back to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, I need to initialize the listener first

```
final OnTestingCBListener onTestingCBListener;
    public void GetFireBaseIDCall(OnTestingCBListener onTestingCBListener, String x, String y){
        if(x.equals("Value1") && y.equals("Value2")) {
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                    final String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                    Log.d("newToken", "Success :)");


                    //This is the problem!!
                    onTestingCBListener = onTestingCBListener;
                    //THIRD
                    onTestingCBListener.onSuccessCB(newToken);
                }
            });

            Log.d("newToken", "Failed :(");
        }
    }
```